# 2-type not-realised in Q

Tags: logic, model-theory

my question is the following: given the additive group of rational numbers, i.e. $Q = \langle {\mathbb Q},+,0\rangle$ and $T$ the theory of $Q$, how can I find (explicitly) a 2-type which is not realised in $Q$?

My guess is the following:
$$\{ \neg(n\cdot v_1 = m\cdot v_2) \mid m,n\in{\mathbb N}^+\}$$
(where $n\cdot v_1$ and $m\cdot v_2$ are just shorthand for $v_1+\ldots +v_1$ and $v_2+\ldots+v_2$)

but this type is realised in $Q$ since i can take e.g. $v_1$=positive and $v_2$=negative; this would realise the type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently, this type would work if Q's domain was the set of *positive* rationals...

Comment: what's a 2-type ?

Comment: @mercio It is a $\mathcal L_A \cup \{x,y\}$-theory that is consistent with $\mathrm{Th}(\mathcal Q,A)$. Where $A \subseteq \mathbb Q$, $\mathcal L_A$ the language $\mathcal L$ of $\mathcal Q$ augmented of constants for each element of $A$, and $x,y$ free variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The type you've written says that $v_1$ and $v_2$ do not have a common natural multiple. Can you write a type that says that $v_1$ and $v_2$ do not have a common *integer* multiple? Use the formula that says $v_1=-v_2$.

Comment: How can you have a minus when the structure only has addition?

Comment: @Nopas The additive inverse $y$ of $x$ is definable by $x + y = 0$.